# Control of outlining in word

Tags: microsoft-word-2003

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, but it seems that if I have a document with multiple nested heading levels displayed in "outline" mode, then word is very quick to forget which headings are "open" or "closed". For example, if I close all the level 2 headings, then close their parent level one heading, then when I re-open the level one heading, all the level 2 headings have become opened again. Similarly, whatever state of open and closed headings I have when I save the document. When it comes to re-loading it, all the headings are now open.

Is there some option to instruct word to leave things open/closed unless instructed otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling around in Word 2002, I'm convinced that Word NEVER remembers the status of any outline items.  If you open an outline file, it's all expanded.  When you open an outline section, it's all expanded. When I open an outline file with everything expanded, collapse all the sections, and then close the file, Word does not ask me whether to save changes, proving to me that expansion status is not a part of the saved document. It appears that collapsing a section in Outline mode suppresses that item from being displayed right then, with no thought for the future.  For some suggestions on more functional outline software, you might check out www.outliners.com.